# SQL Server 2012 result pane

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm taking a database class and we're using SQL Server 2012. I am getting better each day but I'm stuck with this problem I'm having. My cousin was playing with my computer and messing with SQL and i think he change some of the settings.

In class we are just copying examples from the book and plugging in the same information from the book to SQL Server. I should get the same result that the book is showing and I have BUT now that my cousin messed with SQL I can't get the result pane to show the results.

I can see the result pane and at the bottom it says *Query executed successfully* which is a good sign BUT no data is showing up in the result pane.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can`t you compare the data you have with what you are supposed to have?

Comment: Sounds like he might have deleted some or all of the data.

Comment: Where the results would be, make sure you are not on the `Messages` tab. Click `results`

Comment: @Mihai The book has it SELECT CustomerNum, CustomerName, Rep.RepNum, LastName, FirstName
FROM Customer, Rep
WHERE Customer.RepNum=Rep.RepNum
ORDER BY CustomerNum

Comment: There is also an option in the settings that management studio discards all the results after execution, which would cause something like this to happen

Comment: When I click Execute nothing appears in the result box. Just at the bottom it says query executed successfully. In the messages box it say (0 row affected) @JeffreyWieder

Comment: So either `Customer` or `Rep` (or both) are empty or there are no rows that join.

Comment: @JamesZ I'm not that familiar with SQL. do you mean tools and then option? in the option box there is no management studio cards just enviroment, source control, text editor, query execution, query result, designers, sql server always on, sql server object explorer

Comment: You wouldn't see the "0 row affected" message if that option was enabled IIRC.

Comment: @MartinSmith The teacher send us her example just like the book(Access) but in SQL. I copy her inputs and her result appear. I just don't get why my result are not coming up

Comment: I think a screenshot would be quite helpful here.

Comment: Go to the `Query` Menu, near the bottom go to `Results To` and make sure `Results to Grid` is selected.

Comment: What does `print 'Hello'` do?

Comment: im new to stackoverflow. how do i send a screenshot? sorry

Comment: OMG, can't believe what we're helping here with.